# Troubleshooting AMD-Vi IO_PAGE_FAULT

Tags: startup, pci, amd

I have been trying to run Linux on a PC with an AMD CPU. 
The installer for Ubuntu 16.04 loads fine,
but once the OS is loaded on the hard drive upon reboot,
I get a flood of console errors reading:

```
AMD-Vi IO_PAGE_FAULT device=00:14.4 domain=0x0009 address=<varies> flags=0x0000
```

Here is a picture of a few lines of these errors.

[image: photograph of error messages]

At that stage I can only take a photo, no keyboard control.
That device's description which I can get
if I boot a rescue CD or from the recovery shell of the installer:

```
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
```

I have tried installing Fedora, and in that particular case even the installer from the CD fails with the exact same symptom.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/805008/errors-showing-while-booting-16-04-amd-vi-event-logged-io-page-fault